# Adding file names to columns in an appended dataset

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have several ".txt" files that I want to append into a single file (contains two columns, one with wavelength, one with absorbance). I am aiming to have the different files shown in different columns (so they can be plotted on other software afterwards (wavelength vs abs)).

I would like the file names to be shown as the heading/title of each of the columns so I can see which column corresponds to what data file.

I have tried several ways, and what I currently have is

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\pythontest\data')
files = path.glob('*.txt')

to_concat = []
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=17, sep="\t", header=None)
    to_concat.append(df)

result = pd.concat(to_concat, {f.name : pd.read_csv(f) for f in path.glob('*.txt')}, axis=1)
print(result)

result.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\pythontest\data\new\output.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
```

The issue seems to be with the bit...

```
result = pd.concat(to_concat, {f.name : pd.read_csv(f) for f in path.glob('*.txt')}, axis=1)
```

where there is a conflict with the axis

Comment: what was your intention in writing it that way ? what is to_concat and what is the dictionary supposed to you?  Just to get that straight. Your goal is a dataframe which has several columns, always as pair of 2 (1 col for wavelength, 1 col for absorbance). so if you have 5 files, you would have a final df with 10 columns? and the columns itself should have the filename as column name, right?

Comment: I adapted it from something I wrote before. And yes, you are correct, 10 columns for 5 files.

Answer (score 0):

You adapted too much from your old code ;)

if you look closer you'll see that you do the same twice. one time in the for loop you append all the different df of files to `to_concat` and then you do the same in the list comprehension again.

I made 2 test files (names: `first_file.txt` and `second_file.txt`) that look both like this, only different numbers:

```
100 1000
200 2000
300 3000
400 4000
500 5000
```

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'your\path')
files = path.glob('*.txt')

result = pd.concat({f.name : pd.read_csv(f, sep=' ', header=None, names=['wavelength', 'absorbance']) for f in files}, axis=1)
print(result)

result.to_csv(r'result.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode='a')
```

Output `result`:

```
  first_file.txt            second_file.txt           
      wavelength absorbance      wavelength absorbance
0            100       1000               1         10
1            200       2000               2         20
2            300       3000               3         30
3            400       4000               4         40
4            500       5000               5         50
```

with multiindex columns looking like this:

```
print(res.columns)

MultiIndex([( 'first_file.txt', 'wavelength'),
            ( 'first_file.txt', 'absorbance'),
            ('second_file.txt', 'wavelength'),
            ('second_file.txt', 'absorbance')],
           )
```

Be aware that you `to_csv` in `mode='a'` will always append the new data to the end of the file instead of overwriting.